# Inside ngOnint() service method called more than once

Tags: angular, store, lifecycle, function-call, ngoninit

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.pipe(select(empReducer.getErrorStatus)).subscribe(err => this.Error = err);
    this.store.pipe(select(empReducer.getEmpInfo)).subscribe(res=> console.log('test'));
}
```

Console called more than one time why?

Comment: output:test
test
test

Comment: If you replace `subscribe(res=> console.log('test'))` with `subscribe(res=> console.log(res))`, do you get three different strings, or the same thing repeated 3 times?

Comment: I have 2 objects in res , but its called more than twice

Comment: I dont want to call more than once , Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

I see only two possibilities:

1. `empReducer.getEmpInfo` emits more than once.
2. As in the code you provided, there's a subscription, but there's no unsubscription (either with `unsubscribe()`, or with the `takeUntil` pattern) on destroy. If the component is created, destroyed, created again (say, the user goes to another view and back again), you'll have two or more active subscriptions.

Comment: Exactly, remember that observables are streams, so they can emit multiple times. You can use for example `take(1)` inside the pipe to limit it.

Answer (score 1):

As previously advised check the response to see what you are subscribing to. Regarding the subscriptions, you could use this pattern to ensure that all subscriptions get unsubscribed when the component is destroyed. Hope this helps.

```
private _subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();

public ngOnInit():void {

  this._subscriptions.add(
    this.store.pipe(select(empReducer.getErrorStatus)).subscribe(err => this.Error = err)
    )
  );

  this._subscriptions.add(
    this.store.pipe(select(empReducer.getEmpInfo)).subscribe(res => console.log('test')
    )
  );
}

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}
```